# Why doesn't my background sprite scale to my iphone screen?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scaling

I am trying to teach myself swift and spritekit to develop games as a hobby. Why doesn't my sprite scale to my iphone screen? The sprite image is a 2436x1125 px png. My current strategy is to set the size of the GameScene to the UIScreen bounds, and then set the background sprite to the Gamescene size. The resulting background is correct vertically but too small horizontally. It looks like this:

[image]

I set the GameScene size within the View Controller in viewDidLoad:

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scene.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    skView.presentScene(scene)
```

I set the background size and related values in GameScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene
{
var background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "RussiaRing")
var player = Player(restSprite: SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rest 1"))

override func didMove(to view: SKView)
{
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    background.zPosition = -1
    background.size = self.size;
    addChild(background)
    //addChild(player.currentSprite)
}

}
```

Is this a simple fix or am I going about scaling the wrong way? Any advice about best practices for scaling to iphone screens would be much appreciated. Ideally my game will look the same on all newer iphones (iphone 8 and up).

Comment: i do you mean after launch, or after device rotation? i can't reproduce bug for former, only for latter. if you want to resize your sprite *after rotate device* let me know and i can post a proper answer.

Comment: also the line `scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit` should be deleted. you're setting it to `.resizeFill` a few lines later (which is correct for full screen)

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the input. The game launches in landscape left mode only, I have this set in the checkbox in xcode's product information and in AppDelegate with uiOrientationMask = landscapeLeft. The simulator also opens already rotated in landscape mode. I hope this answers your question, I'm an amateur in spritekit so let me know if you need more info.

Comment: sorry, but i can't reproduce the bug using the above code. something must be different between our set ups. wish i could help.